# Remove remaining spaces in the line text file from bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file which reads input from a text file. The text file looks like this:

```
Displayname                                                                    
-----------                                                                    
John Travolta
```

where the name I want to read is in the 4th line (there is an empty line at the beginning)

The problem is that after the last name there are lots of spaces and I want to eliminate those spaces at the end so that the foldername will be `John_Travolta-123` where the spaces not at the end are replaced with underscores but now the foldername appears like this `John_Travolta__________________________________-123` because of the spaces in the end. Below is my script:

```
SET id="123"
set "xprvar="
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%i in ('type "C:\My_User\name.txt"') do if not defined xprvar set "xprvar=%%i"
set foldername=%xprvar%"-"%id%
Set "foldername=%foldername: =_%"
```

Comment: It appears that your file is the content from another command, _probably a [tag:powershell] one_. My advice would therefore be to change that command, such that the output is not in a table format complete with those fixed width spaces. It seems inefficient to try to fix the output after the fact. Perhaps, modifyiing the command using `... | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName | Out-File 'C:\My-User\name.txt'` will help with that.

Comment: @Compo That was it. You can post an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your file is the content from another command, *probably a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) one*.

It seems inefficient to try to fix the output after the fact. My advice would therefore be to change that command, such that the output is not in a table format complete with those fixed width spaces.

Perhaps, modifyiing the command using:

```
... | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\My-User\name.txt'
```

will help with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `~nx` FOR variable modifiers to strip away any trailing spaces as long as your 4th line satisfies all of the following criteria:

- it does not contain any `*`, `?`, `\`, or `/`
- the 2nd character is not `:`
- the last character is not `.`

This works because Windows does not allow a file or folder name to end with a space or `.`

```
set id="123"
set "foldername="
for /F "usebackq skip=3 delims=" %%i in ("C:\My_User\name.txt") do if not defined foldername set "foldername=%%~nxi-%id%"
set "foldername=%foldername: =_%"
```

If you have the hybrid batch/JScript regular expression utility [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) then the solution is very compact, and has no limitations:

```
call jrepl " +$| |$" "|_|-123" /T "|" /F "C:\My_User\name.txt" /RTN foldername:4
```

The JREPL command uses the `/T` option to setup 3 find/replace pairs using `|` as a delimiter. The first pair replaces all trailing spaces with nothing. The second replaces other spaces with underscore, and the last one tacks your ID to the end.

The `/F` option specifies the input file

The `/RTN` option specifies the output variable name that is to receive the 4th line only.